# Android JSon Object Not readable in dotnet webservice for insert operation in REST

Tags: android, json, rest

Json object is returned to a webservice which gets the i/p as

```
[OperationContract(Name = "Create")]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/Create/Data", Method = "POST",
           RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]

bool CreateCustomer(StringBuilder objCustomer);
```

//in my service file im deserializing the i/p obj to my class object and inserting

```
public bool Create(StringBuilder strObj)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        Customer custObj = js.Deserialize<Customer>(strObj.ToString());

        bool Inserted = false;
```

//            connection established and data is put into it

from im asp.net client the obj is serialized to json format  and it can be inserted into my DB but from android, the JSON object which they are sending could not be recognised by my service.. but the response to them goes as "OK 200" ..

the android code is

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000); //Timeout Limit 

HttpResponse response; 
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
String URL ="http://10.242.48.54/restinsert/Service1.svc/Create/Data";
try{ 

    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(URL); 
    json.put("CNo",200);
    json.put("CName","addme");

    StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());
    se.setContentType("application/json; charset=utf-8");
    se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json; charset=utf-8"));

    post.setHeader("Accept","application/json");
    post.setHeader("Content-type","application/json; charset=utf-8");
    String ss= post.toString();

    response = client.execute(post);
```

created a new class for serialize and deserialize

```
public class Json
{
    public string JsontoString(string obj)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        js.Serialize(obj, sb);
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public string StringtoJson(string obj)
    {

        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        Customer custObj = js.Deserialize<Customer>(obj.ToString());
        return custObj.ToString();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: So what you are saying is that you create a JSON object in your Android application and send it to your .NET web service? And your .NET web service cannot parse/deserialize that object? You might want to include the code showing _how_ you create the JSON object in the Android app, otherwise it would be hard to help you...

Comment: yes... but i have the code for creating a json in android and after it requests my service the response shows the status of "OK 200"..but the data is not been accessed by my REST service.. :(

Comment: What do you mean by "not been accessed by my REST service"? Do you get an exception (on the server running the web service) when the web service tries to parse/deserialize the data? If so, you should include the error message in your question to better understand the problem. As I said above as well, it could be useful if you included the code where you create your JSON object in your Android app. So, please update your question with more information/code/error messages, and then maybe somebody will be able to help you.

Comment: there was no error messages.. it shows the response to be perfect from RESTservice.. but my rest service not inserting data... if at all i create a asp.net client and insert, the RESTservice is proper..!!

Comment: this is the andorid code

Comment: hi nailuj i ve added the android code.. is thr any changes to be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having never used the Json Serializer, but having a slight clue about how WCF does its deserialization I would say you can't have StringBuilder as a parameter.

Just change your operation signature to:

```
bool CreateCustomer(Customer customer);
```

WCF wants to do the serialization and deserialization itself, so let it.

Comment: but is it possible for the android client to send object as customer ?? can they deserialze the json to customer obj and send to .net wcf REST??

Answer (score 1):

```
StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString(), "utf-8");
```